# Get a drawable image ID

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable

I have many images in the drawable folder. I want to make the currently selected image as the wall paper on button click.

```
int[] resources = {
    R.drawable.tssr_1,
    R.drawable.tssr_2,
    R.drawable.tssr_3,
    R.drawable.tssr_4,
    R.drawable.tssr_5,
    R.drawable.tssr_6
};

WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
    //set wallpaper picture from resource here
    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.tssr_1);
    //showToast("Success set as wallpaper");
} catch (IOException e) {
  //showToast("Error set as wallpaper");
}
```

Here the `R.drawable.tssr_1` is hardcoded so the application successfully sets the `tssr_1` image as the wall paper image. I want to set the image that is currently showing on the screen. How do I get that image's ID?

Comment: maybe you should call `myWallpaperManager.setResource()` in a `View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener)`

Comment: Thanks li2 for your reply. Would you be able to write a small piece of code? How am I going to go through the array at run time and select the image ID that is currently displayed?

Comment: Are wanting to know how to get an value from your `resources` array?

Comment: Actually I am using a ViewFlipper and wanted to set the current image in the ViewFlipper as wall paper. I didn't know and just found out that ViewFlipper had a method called getDisplayedChild(). That was so dumb of me. I am setting this child index as the wall paper image. Thank you all anyway very much.

Comment: `ViewFlipper.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()`, you should override the listener's `public boolean onLongClick(View v)`

Comment: About image's id, you can set id as image's tag: `View.setTag`, then add image to your `ViewFlipper`. Then in `onLongClick` method, call `View.getTag()` to get resource id.

Comment: Try `myWallpaperManager.setResource(resources[0]);`

Comment: @Anggrayudi **myWallpaperManager.setResource(resources[0]);** worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ViewFlipper vf = new ViewFlipper(getApplicationContext());        
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    // set resId as image's tag, then add to viewflipper.
    image.setTag(imageResId);
    vf.addView(image);

    // the listener will be invoked when image in flipper is clicked and held,
    // then you can set the image as your wall paper. 
    vf.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            int resId = (Integer) v.getTag(); // get image tag 
            myWallpaperManager.setResource(resId);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: The **myWallpaperManager.setResource(resId);** worked, thanks. But now the image exceeds the bounds of the screen. This is what I tried

Comment: This is what I tried

**Bitmap WPimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
               imageIDs[imageIDforWallPaper]);
    
    WallpaperManager wm = (WallpaperManager) getSystemService(WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
    try {
     wm.setBitmap(WPimg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wm.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);**

But the App aborts. Any suggestions to make it work. Thanks

Comment: maybe you should open a new question, and add detail about aborts. Let more people see.